How to run Selenium as the user, and not root?
I'm running a Python script with Selenium to authenticate to a service that opens an app via deep linking.
The script runs remotely with SSH using sudo, but since Selenium is running as sudo, the deep link fails to open the app. Without sudo, it works fine, but I need the script to run with sudo.
Is there a way to run only Selenium as the user while the rest of the script runs with sudo?

Best solution: isolate the parts of your script that call selenium in another script
The easiest / least hacky solution is just to isolate the parts of your script that use selenium. Put them in another script script_selenium.py. that your first script calls with su your_user -c "python script_selenium.py".
Hacky solution:
In the end you just want the deep link to work — that is to run the app. The reason it doesn't work is probably that the app is only installed for your user, in some of their XDG directory.
Chances are if you add that app to $PATH, and change $XDG_DATA_HOME, $XDG_CONFIG_HOME etc. as needed before calling selenium, the link should work

Your description is pretty unspecific. But anyway, browser-automation(=GUI) + sudo smells like an xauth problem. Check if you can see the xauth cookie that the original user (the one who made the SSH connection) acquired, by querying the XAUTHORITY variable after sudo-ing:
user@server ~ % export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority && sudo --preserve-env xauth list
server/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ...

If your output looks similar, try your selenium call again, but with the .Xauthority addition:
user@server ~ % export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority && sudo --preserve-env <your selenium call>

